# array.length function does not output the correct value in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

```
checkoutItems: any[] = [];

updateCheckoutList(){ 

 this.checkoutItems= [];
 let shopID = sessionStorage.getItem("shop") 

 for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  let key = localStorage.key(i);
  this.itemsService.getCheckoutItem(key, shopID).subscribe((response: any) => { 
    let checkoutItem = response; 
    for (let k of checkoutItem){
      this.checkoutItems.push(k);
    } 
    });
 } 

console.log(this.checkoutItems);
console.log(this.checkoutItems.length);
}
```

The Console log of (this.checkoutItems) returns this,

```
 0: {item_id: 2, item_name: "paan", image: "thisurl", price: 630}
 1: {item_id: 1, item_name: "bread", image: "location", price: 620}
 2: {item_id: 3, item_name: "med", image: "", price: 250}

 length: 3

__proto__: Array(0)
```

but the console log of the (checkoutItems.length) prints 0, Why is it happening? I'm sorry I'm new to typescript

Comment: The callback given to `.subscribe` is invoked asynchronously. Your array does not have items placed into it until *after* your calls to `console.log`.

Comment: my items are already placed into it, the first console log displays it perfectly, my problem was as to why the array.length function doesnt work on an array that already has items placed into it

Comment: When using `console.log` in chrome, the logged object is a reference to the original, so it will update when the original does (so by the time you look at it, it has data in it). But the data is still being put there after the log happens. You can verify that by logging the json representation of your value: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.checkoutItems))`, you'll see that it's empty.